# How to use a value from a function and pass it down to another function python

Tags: python

This is a much-simplified version of my program but has the same idea:

```
def calc():
   x=1
   y=2
   z=6
def output():
   final=x+y+z
```

how can I use the return values in the first function to be used in the second?

Comment: Values from a function are only available outside it if you `return` them

Answer (score 2):

The method `calc` must return the values to allow `output` to retrieve them when calling it.

I deliberately changed the name of the variables in the `output` method, so you see, they are not related and can be named as you want.

```
def calc():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 6
    return x, y, z

def output():
    a, b, c = calc()
    final = a + b + c
    print(final)  # 9

if __name__ == '__main__':
    output()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calc():
    x=1
    y=2
    z=6
    return x + y + z # you need to use 'return' in order for function to return some values

def output():
    final = calc()
```

or

```
def calc():
    x=1
    y=2
    z=6
    return x, y, z # you need to use 'return' in order for function to return some values

def output():
    x, y, z = calc()
    final = x + y + z
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
def calc():
    x=1
    y=2
    z=6
    return x, y, z

def output(values):
    x, y, z = values
    final = x + y + z
    return final

print(output(calc()))
```